# C# bool object property validation

Tags: c#

I have a class `Shoes` with a bool property to check if shoes are secondhand or not.

```
class Shoes
{        
    private bool secondhand;

    public bool IsSecondHand
    {
        get { return secondhand; }
        set
        {
            if (value == ) //don't know what to use here
            {
                value = false;
            }
            else
            {
               //is true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to use this class (separate file) with a WPF window and using a `checkbox` that when checked makes my bool true, otherwise is false. I need to preserve the format get {} set {}. The problem is that this proprety should "work" even without the WPF part.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse whatever is passed in `value` ? , it looks like you are trying to set value to `false` in true case of your if statement and true otherwise.? is that the case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just simply do:

```
set
{
   secondhand = value;
}
```

Or, as @JFM suggests, you can simply use an auto property and you no longer need to explicitly declare the backing field:

```
public bool IsSecondHand {get; set;}
```

Comment: or just? -> public bool IsSecondHand {get;set;}

Comment: @JFM That won't set the private field

Comment: @MatiasCicero I think the suggestion is that a private backing field does not seem necessary here.

Comment: @crashmstr Can't really tell, OP may be showing us only a portion of the whole class

Comment: @Matias Cicero, well it's not exactly used either